# Utility to cat/gunzip a list of files

Tags: linux, file-management, gzip, cat

Is there a commonly-installed Linux utility that will take a list of files and `cat` or `gzip -d` (==`zcat`) them based on whether the file is compressed?

An example of where I just needed this is when I want to examine `/var/log/messages` files, including both the logrotated ones (`/var/log/messages-{date}.gz`) and the current file.

I'll likely add something like the following to my `~/.zshrc`:

```
catz () {
    local file
    for file ; do
        case $file in
            *gz*) gzip -d < $file ;;
            *bz*) bzip -d < $file ;;
            *xz*|*lz*) xz -d < $file ;;
            *) cat $file ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

But, I'm not always on a machine where I have my rc installed, so I was hoping for a more general solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`less` does that.

```
less /var/log/messages*
```

If you pipe the output of `less` to another program, `less` will behave like `cat` or `gunzip -c` and not page the output.

Comment: Specifically, whatever program specified by $LESSPIPE does that.  I tried that exact command earlier, was annoyed at having to ':n'/':p' through the list of files, and wrote the question.  Coming back to this, I got what I'm actually going to use: `less /var/log/messages* | less`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The "more general solution" that you're looking for is to train your fingers to type out `zcat -f …` instead of trying to flip back and forth between `zcat` and `cat`.

By the way:

- `zgrep` will search through both compressed and uncompressed files without an additional flag.
- `bzcat -f` behaves like `zcat -f` - both will simply output (without decompressing) files that are not in their native compression format instead of understanding that it's a different compressed format and sub-forking off the right decompression program.